# Xcode 11 "Show SwiftUI Inspector" doesn't show up correctly when accessed from the code (cmd + tap on part of the code)

Tags: macos, swiftui, xcode11, macos-catalina

I am running latest released macOS version on 15" MacBook Pro 2017, 256gb, tried Xcode 11 latest release and also latest Xcode beta. When I am trying to CMD + Tap on part of the CODE in SwiftUI it appears with a bug, content is too high, so I cannot access anything. [Here's image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3Dix.png).
Maybe someone knows how to fix. Please, excuse me if this question is dumb.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I got fixed by itself overnight. btw: tried to reboot Mac and it didn't help (maybe it saved Xcode processes), it just magically got fixed, maybe some bugged process has gone overnight. I had to disable all Xcode processes, I think